# Redirect an old link to new site homepage

Tags: htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect a single link `www.abc.com/blog/?p=123` to `www.abc.com/newblog/`

I have used:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/newblog/ [R=301,L]
```

It is redirecting all sorts of links but missing links in the form `/?p=1236`.

Answer (score 1):

Query arguments are in `%{QUERY_STRING}`, so you have to look there:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=\d+
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/newblog/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Didn't get it quite. I need this single url. And where is the string "blog" gone?

Comment: What “single URL”? You can add the prefix in your own solution, I just show the general way.